# MalformedURLException protocol not found?

Tags: java, android, malformedurlexception

I am working with an a image cache/download library..

i am getting the url of the image from a data model as a String: https://s3.amazonaws.com/knuser9/ae2f40a6-c563-4f9d-ade4-beb8d373ebc3.png

but when i pass that url to the execute() of my Async task i get the following error:

```
>     06-18 12:01:09.273: E/getImage(28140): java.net.MalformedURLException:  Protocol not found:
> https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fknuser9%2Fae2f40a6-c563-4f9d-ade4-beb8d373ebc3.png
```

I am a little losted as to what is going on.. the url is good, we know that.. when i log the url before the task its formatted exactly like this:

> https://s3.amazonaws.com/knuser9/ae2f40a6-c563-4f9d-ade4-beb8d373ebc3.png

but then it gets all wonky?

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding the whole url, so it is encoding https:// into https%3A%2F%2Fs3. Thats why you are getting the error.

Comment: well that did not work i stripped out the https:// and still got a malformed url exception:  java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: s3.amazonaws.com/knuser9/ae2f40a6-c563-4f9d-ade4-beb8d373ebc3.png

Comment: @erik As Nathan stated.

Comment: actually the solution was just to replace https:  with http: in the url string before encoding it..

Comment: @erik You have to encode only the header. In your case, it is ae2f40a6-c563-4f9d-ade4-beb8d373ebc3.png

Comment: its working just by replacing the https with http, i guess i am not understanding your point.